# Moving through objects in form

Tags: c#, winforms

Is there a way to move through objects in windows forms? (for example: buttons)

I want to disable a specific button based on an input. 
For Example: If I have 100 buttons, and got an input of 65, I want to make a loop that moves through all buttons until the 65th button.
Is that possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Look for `Controls` property of your form. Also `Name` or `Tag` properties of controls to distinguish between them.

Comment: Well you could make a cascading function that iterates through form1.controls and the children looking for buttons.
Not wery efficient though

Comment: I hope you don't actually have 100 buttons in a form. That would be horrible. If you are making a Minesweeper game then better draw everything by yourself.

Comment: Hehehehe it was an exaggeration, not going to have 100 buttons, it was just for the sake of the question :)

Comment: Are those buttons created dynamically? Else you don't need looping.

Comment: No, I already created the buttons, just need to find a specific button and change it properties.

Comment: Why not assign ID to these buttons then? IDs would be named like `btn1`, `btn2`.. `btnN` and then just pick desired one based on input without looping through all buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Keep your buttons in a List. Then send as a parameter to this function

```
private void EnabledButtons(List<Button> listButton, int count)
{
   foreach (Button btn in listButton)
   {
       btn.Enabled = false;
   }
   // or
   for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
   {
       listButton[i].Enabled = false;
   }            
}
```

Comment: Standard buttons don't have controls inside. Don't need the inner loop.

Comment: Edited :) @Dialecticus